# How to parse a signals and slot statements written in python?

Tags: python, parsing, pyqt, pyqt4, instrumentation

I am writing a python script to extract particular  information from a PyQt application. My exact goal is to extract  the signals that are being emitted during runtime of the application.

Basically I will be instrumenting(inserting my code fragments) the application in specific places where emit code fragment is written. Due to the instrumentation during runtime i will be getting the information about the signals that are emitted.

I would like to explain with a scenario:

```
Normal scenario
#A.py(actual code)

#start of a file

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
....
....
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("Button_pressed"))
....
....

#end of a file

Instrumented Scenario

#A.py(actual code)

#start of a file

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
....
....
signal_sent="Button_pressed" 
print signal_sent
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("Button_pressed"))
....
....

#end of a file
```

(**Note ""Button_pressed" value can be assigned to "signal_sent"only if i am able to parse the "emit" statement so that I can extract the string " Button_pressed")

Problem statement: My objective is to parse exactly the emit statement  in the file so that i can retrieve the string present in the signal? How can i parse the statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by writing the following emit signal:-

```
self.emit(Qt.SIGNAL("buttonPressed(QString)"),"Button_pressed")
```

and the following connect:-

```
self.connect(self, Qt.SIGNAL("buttonPressed(QString)"), self.functionCall)
```